# Does there exists a one time differentiable function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

> Does there exists a **only one time** differentiable function $f$ in an interval $[a,b]$ whose derivative is monotone increasing in $[a,b]$ ? That is, does there exists a function $f$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f'$ exists for all $x\in [a,b]$ and $f'$ is monotone increasing in $[a,b]$ but $f''$ does not exists at some point in $[a,b]$.

I guess there exists such a function. I'm trying to define such function but unable!!

Any hint?

Comment: If a function is non-decreasing, its derivative exists almost everywhere... But take the function $f'(x) = \chi_{[0,\infty)}x$ (i.e., $f(x) = \int_0^x\chi_{[0,\infty)}(t)t\,dt$). That's an example.

Comment: @amsmath Edited. Please recheck it.

Comment: Check out my example. $f(x)$ is zero for negative $x$ and otherwise a parabola.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb R$ by
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0&\text{for $x<0$}\\
x^2&\text{for $x\ge 0$}
\end{cases}.
$$